# Roslyn Diagnostic Analyzer's diagnosis not reflecting in Visual Studio instance

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, roslyn

I am trying to detect the passing of a model as a parameter to a function in a controller for a MVC application. I have written a code for a Roslyn Diagnostic Analyzer. The logic behind the code works fine as the breakpoints are hit as intended. But the diagnostic result in terms of warning is not reflected in the visual studio instance opened.

This is the code snippet of my diagnostic analyzer:

```
public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
{
    // TODO: Consider registering other actions that act on syntax instead of or in addition to symbols
    context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeSymbol, SyntaxKind.MethodDeclaration);
}

private async static void AnalyzeSymbol(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
{
    var method = (MethodDeclarationSyntax)context.Node;

    ParameterListSyntax ParamList = method.ParameterList;
    int flag = 0;
    string ParamName = null;

    foreach (ParameterSyntax Param in ParamList.Parameters)
    {
        if (Param.Type.ToString().Contains("Model"))
        {
            ParamName = Param.Type.ToString();
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (flag == 0)
        return;

    string solutionPath = @"C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WebApplication6\WebApplication6.sln";
    var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();                                                       
    var solution = await workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(solutionPath);

    foreach (var project in solution.Projects)
    {
        foreach (var document in project.Documents)
        {
            CancellationToken source = default(CancellationToken);

            SyntaxNode root = await document.GetSyntaxRootAsync(source);

            var classDeclarations = root.DescendantNodes().Where(n => n.IsKind(SyntaxKind.ClassDeclaration));
            flag = 0;

            foreach (ClassDeclarationSyntax cls in classDeclarations)
            {
                if (cls.Identifier.Text.ToString() == ParamName)
                {

                        var diagnostic = Diagnostic.Create(Rule, method.GetLocation());
                        context.ReportDiagnostic(diagnostic);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: no info in the error or output pane of the test instance?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel There are no errors. But the program shows following exceptions in output window :
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Core.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileLoadException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' in mscorlib.dll
on thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.InvalidComObjectException' in mscorlib.dll

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct version of the analyzer template?  You need to have the one that matches your install of VS 2015 (i.e. if you are using RC then have the RC template).  Also, verify your analyzer is installed in the instance or project.

Comment: Are you running your analyzer on `WebApplication6.sln`? You may have issues opening an MSBuildWorkspace on a solution that is already being built.

Comment: @JoshVarty Yes, I am running the analyzer on a different solution.

Comment: It could be related to this bug: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/3748

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are incorrect searching of classes. You should operate with context and should not open new solution. Context contains all necessary information about opened solution.

Comment: That should not really matter so long as the `context.ReportDiagnostic()` is called, and that does not solve the problem.